# Performance: Why does AngularJS evaluate watch when scope model hasn't changed?

Tags: performance, angularjs, scope, watch

So I have a watch on scope A. Why does AngularJS evaluate it when a local variable on sibling scope B changes? The data model of scope A hasn't changed.

Here is a minimal example of this:

- there is a custom watch on scope A.
- the input element is bound to the `text` variable of scope B.
- Note that the `text` is not shown, because it's not visible from scope A.

*Controllers:*

```
function Ctrl1($scope) {

    console.log($scope); // first scope

    // my custom watch expression
    var count = 0;
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        count++;
        console.log("call count: " + count);
    }, function() {
        // the listener does nothing
        // I'm just interested in when the watch expression is called
    });

}

function Ctrl2($scope) {        
    console.log($scope); // second scope        
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">        
        {{text}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Feel free to try this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Wz5/4/ )

If you type some text in the input element (scope B), the custom watch of the scope A is evaluated. Why is this? Why doesn't AngularJS know that there are no changes to the data model of scope A whatsoever?

**Update: Some clarification:**
I don't want to watch `text`. This is a performance related question, wondering why the watch is evaluated even though `text` cannot possibly be read from the other scope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$watch` is evaluated in every digest cycle. Change value of a [`ng-model`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) triggers digest cycle. This behavior is different from `$scope.$digest()`, which only triggers digestion on current and child scopes.

I think `ng-model` might NOT use `$scope.$digest()` internally. It might use some other mechanism to trigger digest after value changes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, digest just calls watches in the current scope and child scopes. I'm asking why is it called on a sibling scope?

Comment: @Chris when user change the value of `ng-model` I don't think Angular can figure out on what level of scope the property is attached to. Thus no way to trigger digest just for specific scope (and its children).

Comment: @Chris I know `$scope.$digest()` only triggers digest on current and child scopes, but that doesn't necessary mean `ng-model` will use `$digest` internally.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate for bigger web pages =/ If you edit your answer to include your comments, I'll accept it as the answer